What does the 6363 stamp on my son's passport mean?
My son wanted to return to the UK from Romania and at the border the officer put a stamp on his passport and sent him back to Romania.
The number on his passport is 6363.

What is you son’s citizenship and age? What were his plans in the UK?

At which border? And did the officer confiscate the passport, to be able to "send it back"? If so, how did your son enter UK?

What did the stamp actually look like? You can edit your post to add a picture (with any personal details blacked out).

A stamp with a “cross" drawn through it means leave to enter the UK was refused. 6363 is just the number of the officer that processed your son.
There’s an example of such a stamp in this question

If the 6363 is printed inside the stamp that the UK Immigration Officer used, then it is a number used to identify that particular officer.
